# Wordpress: How to shgw posts where custom field value matches current post ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display posts (various custom post types) where the value for a field ('author_company') matches the ID of the current post. The current post in this situation is a profile for a company. Basically I'm wanting to display posts which have been associated with that company by way of a relationship field.

I have the relationship field 'author_company' on each custom post type ('article', 'press_release', 'video', 'podcast') where I pick from the list of companies (custom post type 'company').

When checking the database, I can see that the 'author_company' field stores the post ID of the company, so on the company template I'm trying to display those posts like so:

```
global $post;
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$company_posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'article', 'press_release', 'podcast', 'video',
    'meta_key'      => 'author_company',
    'meta_value'    => $post_id
));
foreach($company_posts as $company_post) :
setup_postdata($company_post);
```

But... nothing. I get no results and I'm totally stumped. I've double checked the current post ID (the company) and it definitely matches the 'author_company' field value for the posts I want to display.

To summarise:

1. Custom post types 'article', 'press_release', 'podcast', and 'video' have a relationship field called 'author_company'
2. 'author_company' stores the ID of another custom post type ('company') of my choice
3. On the 'company' post type template, I want to display posts where the 'author_company' field value matches the current post ID (i.e. the company ID)

Any thoughts? Am I missing something really obvious? Thank you!

Comment: `'post_type' => 'article', 'press_release', 'podcast', 'video',` does not do what you think it should. You need to provide either _one_ string value, or an array.

Comment: sh*t you're right, I can't believe I did that... thank you.... sorry